# dynamic countdown timer with hooks (React Native)

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a set of numbers that are saved into redux for a set of exercises. When you are in each exercise's page and press complete the timer would count down all the to zero and then reset to the original number.

So I would set the original value using `useState`.

`const [count, setCount] = useState({ReduxValue});`

But then I would use `useEffect` to do the count down and reseting the number to the original value, right? What would `useEffect` call though? the initial state value (`setInitialTime`)?
And would I use the same `useEffect` to reset the value?

**Edit:**
This is what I have so far. Once the number gets to zero it freaks out and the next time around during the count down it looks like it is skipping or jumping numbers.

```
   function Counter() {
      const [count, setCount] = useState({ReduxValue});
      const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
    
      function startTimer() {
        setCount({ReduxValue});
        setIsActive(true);
      }
    
      useEffect(() => {
        let interval = null;
        if (isActive) {
          interval = setInterval(() => {
            count - 1 < 0 ? setCount(5) : setCount(count - 1);
          }, 1000);
        } else if (!isActive && count != 0) {
          clearInterval(setInterval);
        }
      });
```

Comment: Would be better to provide a code example?

Comment: I added a code example but I'm trying to think on how it would reset to the original redux value and also how to only start the countdown when a button is pressed. How would a function be called to run the useEffect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use the boolean to trigger the countdown.
2. After the countdown finishes, you can update your redux state.

```
function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(10);
  const [startCountdown, setStartCountdown] = React.useState(false);


  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (startCountdown) {
      const timer = counter > 0 && setInterval(() => setCounter(counter - 1), 100);

      if (counter === 0) {
        // countdown is finished
        setStartCountdown(false);
        // update your redux state here
        // updateReduxCounter(0);
      }
      
      return () => clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, [counter, startCountdown]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Countdown: {counter}</div>
      <button onClick={() => setStartCountdown(true)}>Start Countdown</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```